# Parcelable error occurred while using the Room

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-room, parcelable

Parcelable error occurred while using the Room.

I'm studying Room, but I don't have much common sense yet. So I don't know why I use Parcelable.

I think there was an error when changing the format of Room to one to many.

error mesage :

```
error: (goalId) does not exist in com.example.goalapp.db.entity.Goal. Available columns are id,goalName

public final class TodayGoal implements android.os.Parcelable {
                                                              ^
```

Entity related code :

```
//Goal table
@Parcelize
@Entity(tableName = "goal_table")
data class Goal(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int,
    val goalName: String,
): Parcelable


//todayGoal table
@Parcelize
@Entity(
    tableName = "today_goal_table",
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Goal::class,
            parentColumns = ["goalId"],
            childColumns = ["id"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )
    ]
)
data class TodayGoal(
    val id: Int,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val todayGoalId: Int,
    val TodayGoalName: String,
): Parcelable


//GoalAndTodayGoal
@Parcelize
data class GoalAndTodayGoals(
    @Embedded val goal: Goal,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "goalId",
        entityColumn = "id"
    )
    val todayGoals: List<TodayGoal>
): Parcelable
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error say, `goalId` does not exist in `Goal` class. Try to change the `id` attribute of `Goal` to `goalId`.

```
@Parcelize
@Entity(tableName = "goal_table")
data class Goal(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val goalId: Int,
    val goalName: String,
): Parcelable
```

Answer (score 0):

**The Issue**

Your issue is that the reference, in the ForeignKey definition as per `parentColumns = ["goalId"],`, is not pointing to a column that exists in the parent (**Goal**) table.

The respective (suitable) column is named **id** as per     `@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int,`

- if you used the **goalName** column that Room tells you is an available column then you would get a subsequent error as the **goalName** column is not UNIQUE.

  - a `ForeignKey` must reference a parent column (or combination of columns) that is/are `UNIQUE`, as SQLite must be able to ascertain the exact parent not one of more than one parent.

**Potential Fixes**

**1.** change the **id** column name to be **goalId** so either:-

```
val goalId: Int,
```

or if you want the field/member name to remain as **id** then :-

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "goalId")
val id: Int
```

- **Note one of these 2 solutions would be suggested as the better solutions.**

**2.** Change, to use `parentColumns = ["id"],`.

- **However**, using **id** as column, if not the only column named id, in related tables, can lead to ambiguities (what id column).

  - this issue would not be encountered if not using `JOIN` in a `SELECT` statement.
  - The ambiguity and can be circumvented, by using `JOIN` along with using exact column names, of the ambiguous columns prefixed by the table name and separated from the column name by a **`.`**, but that can lead to rather lengthy SQL.

**3.** Another option would be to do away with the `ForeignKey` definition altogether **BUT** even though it isn't needed

- ForeignKey does not define a relationship, but instead creates a rule *(a **constraint** in SQLite terminology) that enforces referential integrity*
- However, you then lose the built-in assurance of referential integrity and the automatic maintenance of the referential integrity (deletion of a parent being **CASCADE**ed (i.e. the children being deleted if the parent is deleted)).